# How to set full control to a directory

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to set full control

```
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = source.GetAccessControl();
string User = "Srinivass\\Admin";
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(
                        User,
                        FileSystemRights.Modify,
                        InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                        PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
                        AccessControlType.Allow)
                    );

source.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

But it is giving special permissions to this folder only.
I want to give full controll permissions to all subfolders.

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 19):

Try changing `PropagationFlags` parameter to `PropagationFlags.None`.

Your access rule should look like:

```
 new FileSystemAccessRule( 
          User, 
          FileSystemRights.FullControl,
          InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
          PropagationFlags.None,
          AccessControlType.Allow 
  );
```

Then, check the Security tab in Windows Explorer, and you should see the folder (and any newly created objects going forward) having **Full Control**.

Comment: PropagationFlags.None seems to have been the ticket in my case.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 too bad I cannot upvote more. It's late at night and I've been struggling with this. Long live SO